# LED, 2 way switch wiring not working

Tags: led, wiring

I will give as much information as I can, but my knowledge is limited.

There is a staircase with a 2 way switch. 
There are 10 LED lights throughout the stairs. They are using direct current.

The old LEDs were taken out and now I have 10 holes with 2 wires each. I GUESS one wire is positive (+) and the other is negative (-).

When I connect ALL of my new LEDs, each postivie to the positive wire in the wall and each negative to the negative wire in the wall, all of them light up extremely low.

After that, I tried to connect them one by one to see what happens.

To do so, I connected all the wires from the wall with each other (1st hole's 2 wires were connected together, 2nd hole's 2 wires were connected together, etc) and in one hole only, I connected my LED (tried the wires to see where it lit up, knowing this way, the positive and negative). The light that came out was bright and as it should be.

So next, I left everything as is, and connected one more LED to another hole. Once I did that, the light was again extremely low as it was when I connected all of them.

Any ideas of what is happening or what I am doing wrong?

The new LEDs are from an LED strip that was cut, and 2 wires were solder, one on the positive and one on the negative.

I am adding a schematic, have in mind I have nothing to do with electrical engineering. Just trying to make it easier to understand what I am talking about.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fF3LEr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For further details, if you need something I can check that have not said above, please ask me.

Thank you!

New (transformer/adapter)
[image: New one]
New LED
[image: new LED strip]

Old (transformer/adapter)
[image: Old one]

Old LED
[image]

Comment: Are the new LEDs the same colour as the old LEDs? How old were the old LEDs?

Comment: They are the same colour but they told me they are "power LEDs". Is there a difference? The old ones where from +-2010

Comment: They could have a different (higher) forward voltage, which could decrease the current going through them, depending on the driving circuitry. How is the DC generated?

Comment: I added a photo, hope it helps!

Comment: old  supply DC rating is upto 33 V and the new one is only 12 V, as i see

Comment: True but, one thing I forgot, before connecting them to the wall, I connected them all together (all positives as one and all negatives as one) and then connected them to the DC supply and they all worked correctly. The distance of the wires from top to bottom is around 15 meters.

Comment: @vskand did you just connect LEDs without any current limiting circuit? For testing..

Comment: Yes, all LEDs where connected direclty to the power supply

Comment: Please drop some information about the type of LED lights. Model No., manufacturer, rating etc.

Comment: The two transformers / adapters are completely different, you can't just replace one with another. The white one is a "led driver", it's a fixed current supply, which feeds fixed 350 mA, from 0 to 33 V. The black one is a normal DC power supply which feeds fixed (almost fixed) 12v, from 0 to 2.5 A. The wiring of the leds should be different for each adapter. If you're using the black one, you should use resistors.

Comment: What I did not mention is that the new LEDs are from an LED strip that cas cut, and 2 wires were solder, one on the positive and one on the negative. That's why there is a difference in the supplies

Comment: do you mean "led strip that has been cut"? Most of led strips have resistors inside, when cutting then, where did the resistors went? If I were using a 12v DC supply, I would use connect the leds in series of 3, adding a load resistor of about 100 ohm to each serie. The tenth led would be connected alone, with a load resistor (a larger one), too. If I were using the white adapter, I would connect the 10 leds in series, but make sure that they're power leds (about 1W) with good thermal dissipation.

Comment: I am updating the post with 2 images. Hope they help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original LEDs were driven by a constant-current source and were therefore wired in series.

Your replacement LEDs need to be driven by a constant voltage, and therefore need to be wired in parallel, which is how you bench-tested them.

You're going to have to figure out a way to repurpose the wires inside the wall in order to get the LEDs connected in parallel rather than in series. It may be necessary to pull new wires.

---

> I found out each hole in the hole has the 2 cables the old LEDs used AND 2 more cables, that were wrapped together. So now I have 4 cables. Each pair, has a positive and a negative. Any idea what I should do?

That's actually good news. It means that you don't need to pull any new wires.

What you likely have is "zip cord" running from hole to hole, wired something like this (original setup):

[image: schematic]

You just need to reconnect the wires in the holes like this:

[image: schematic]

Comment: Did you figure that out from the two supplies?
Is it 100% that they were wired in series and now have to be parallel? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, and yes...

Comment: Perfect, thanks, will see if that's possible!

Comment: Hi again and sorry for the late reply. I need some more help. I found out each hole in the hole has the 2 cables the old LEDs used AND 2 more cables, that were wrapped together. So now I have 4 cables. Each pair, has a positive and a negative. Any idea what I should do? I cannot get them to light up!! Thanks

Comment: See edit above. Let me know if anything isn't clear.

Comment: Hi, so I connected all blue wires together, all brown wires together, found out which one was positive and which was negative (blue was negative, brown positive) connected each positive wire from the led to the brown and each negative to the blue and as you would expected, it worked. I am sure it seems trivial to you, but you saved me money and time!! Appreciate it! Thank you!!